# Можно ли самостоятельно прошить металлоискатель?

Tags: железо, прошивка

Как прошить *Clone PI AVR* и смогу ли я сам его прошить?

Comment: Если есть программатор для Atmega8 (например с USB интерфейсом), то вполне реально.